# Sequelize literal with limit and offset params incorrect query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have next models:

```
const Picture = sequelize.define<IPictureInstance>('picture', {
 id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
 img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
 mainTitle: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
 description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT }
});

const PictureType = sequelize.define('pictureType', {
 id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
 name: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
});
```

And their connections:

```
PictureType.hasMany(Picture);
Picture.belongsTo(PictureType);
```

I'm trying to get a list op pictureTypes with amount of pictures, for that, i created the next query:

```
const pictureTypes = await models.PictureType.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pictures AS picture WHERE picture.pictureTypeId = pictureType.id)`), "picturesAmount"]
    ]
  },
  limit: limitValue,
  offset: offsetValue
});
 return pictureTypes;
};
```

But as a result i've got the next message: "столбец picture.picturetypeid не существует" which translated as: "column picture.picturetypeid doesn't exists".

What the problem is? Would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS you need to wrap columns with special characters or in mixed case into `"` (usually PostgreSQL) or backticks (MySQL) so DBMS would interpret this column name nor trying to convert it to lower case.

```js
const pictureTypes = await models.PictureType.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pictures AS picture WHERE picture."pictureTypeId" = pictureType.id)`), "picturesAmount"]
    ]
  },
  limit: limitValue,
  offset: offsetValue
});
 return pictureTypes;
};
```